# How to indicate a cut out for a product window

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, shapes, print-production

I just started learning package design. I have finished my artwork and want to send the final file to the customer.

The design has a product window. How should I indicate this layer in Illustrator? How do I tell the printer they have to cut this shape out?

Comment: Hi Keemie. Can you indicate if this is a box or a label? Were you provided with a technical drawing (of the cutting die)?

Answer (score 6):

- Use a separate layer for the cut out (window) artwork and move this on top of the layer stack.
- Apply a distinct color swatch to the outline of this window shape and make it a spot color.
- Select this shape and set it to 'Overprint Stroke' in the 'Attributes' panel.

Comment: Magenta is what we always used, because I can't recall a single print job in 10 years which used magenta as an actual color in the job. The layer was also called something like WINDOW DO NOT PRINT.

Comment: I would not use Magenta as such, but a magent-ish spot color. So the color selection is untouched and a spot ink pops as a separate plate if someone did not see the "do not print me" sign.

Answer (score 2):

I must make a warning.

A window is not made just because. Every wall forms an intrinsic part of the structure of the box.

The answer is really simple. The window is presented exactly the same way as the dies or cuts of the full box.

Do you know how to prepare all the project? And how to structure a box? If you do not, ask the printer to prepare the diagrams for you.